# SQL query if row count is empty then do another query

Tags: sql, join, left-join, not-exists

I am trying to access 2 tables, 1 is a job table and the other is a call out sheets that are assigned to the job table.

Basically not all jobs have call out sheets assigned to them, and the way I originally did this was fine if sheets was assigned but does not count the ones that do not have sheets assigned.

Here is my original code:

```
$getQuery = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT 
sheet.id, sheet.jid, sheet.jd,sheet.tos,sheet.toffs,sheet.miles,sheet.mrate,sheet.r1,sheet.r2,sheet.r3,sheet.r4,sheet.r5,sheet.r6,sheet.r7,sheet.r8,job.cid, job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc 
FROM 
jSheets sheet 
LEFT JOIN jobs job ON(sheet.jid = job.id) 
WHERE job.cc=:cc AND jd >= :jd AND jd <= :jd2 
ORDER BY id DESC
");
$getQuery->execute(array(':cc' => $typecostcode, ':jd' => $postDateFrom, ':jd2' => $postDateToo));
```

I tried to change this so that to my logic if this comes back not existing/row count = 0 then do another query.

But I can not get this to work.

I have been looking on this website among a few others from Google searches but can not grasp the query needed to get this to work.

Here is the code I thought would correct the issue with if no sheets exist then do another query:

```
$getQuery = $pdo->prepare("
SELECT 
job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc,sheet.tos,sheet.toffs,sheet.miles,sheet.mrate,sheet.r1,sheet.r2,sheet.r3,sheet.r4,sheet.r5,sheet.r6,sheet.r7,sheet.r8 
FROM jobs job 
LEFT JOIN jSheets sheet ON(job.id = sheet.jid) 
WHERE job.cc=:cc AND sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2 
AND NOT EXISTS (
job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc 
FROM jobs 
WHERE job.cc=:cc AND job.jobdate >= :jd AND sheet.jobdate <= :jd2) 
ORDER BY id DESC
");
$getQuery->execute(array(':cc' => $typecostcode, ':jd' => $postDateFrom, ':jd2' => $postDateToo));
```

I can not get this to work, not sure if its the query or the execute binds because I only get the following error:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): in
>   C:\wamp\www\Applications\Controllers\Jobs\report.php on line 152

But I am only using the 3 variables and even if I do a jd, jd2, jd3, jd4 I still get the same error.

--- EDIT ---

After taking what 3BS said regarding using an IF statement I altered the code to the following:

```
$getQuery = $pdo->prepare("
                IF(
                    SELECT COUNT (*)
                    FROM jsheets sheet 
                    LEFT JOIN jobs job ON(sheet.jid = job.id) 
                    WHERE sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2 LIMIT 1
                ) > 0
                BEGIN
                    SELECT job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc,sheet.tos,sheet.toffs,sheet.miles,sheet.mrate,sheet.r1,sheet.r2,sheet.r3,sheet.r4,sheet.r5,sheet.r6,sheet.r7,sheet.r8 FROM jobs job LEFT JOIN jsheets sheet ON(job.id = sheet.jid) WHERE sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SELECT id,cid,cc,ref,ac,reference,status,jdesc FROM jobs WHERE jobdate >= :jd AND jobdate <= :jd2) ORDER BY id DESC
                END
            ");
            $getQuery->execute(array(':jd' => $postDateFrom, ':jd2' => $postDateToo));
```

I am still getting the following warning, and again I do not know if it is the query or the PDO execute that is the issue:

> Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): in
>   C:\wamp\www\Applications\Controllers\Jobs\report.php on line 152

---

**The jobs table columns are as follows:**

id, cid, cc, ref, ttotal, wtotal, ac, qble, reference, status, gen, jdesc, noengineer, jobdate

---

**The Sheet columns are as follows:**

id, jid, jd, tos, toffs, miles, mrate, tt, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, status

---

--- EDIT END ---

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you put all your conditions in PHP?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after you explained you're using MySQL, and cause my answer was sql-server related. Here is the If condition use in MySQL, IF(expression, true, false):

```
select  IF( (
            SELECT COUNT jd
            FROM jsheets sheet 
            LEFT JOIN jobs job ON(sheet.jid = job.id) 
            WHERE sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2 LIMIT 1  
            ) > 0 ,
            (
            SELECT job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc,sheet.tos,sheet.toffs,sheet.miles,sheet.mrate,sheet.r1,sheet.r2,sheet.r3,sheet.r4,sheet.r5,sheet.r6,sheet.r7,sheet.r8
            FROM jobs job LEFT JOIN jsheets sheet ON(job.id = sheet.jid)
            WHERE sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2
            FROM jobs job
            LEFT JOIN jsheets sheet ON(job.id = sheet.jid) WHERE sheet.jd >= :jd AND sheet.jd <= :jd2
            ),
            (
            SELECT id,cid,cc,ref,ac,reference,status,jdesc
            FROM jobs WHERE jobdate >= :jd AND jobdate <= :jd2)
            )
        )
 ORDER BY id DESC
```

--- End edit ---

you have a SQL Syntax error here

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc
```

when using a NON EXIST clause with a subquery, your subquery must have logical sense, it should be like:

```
AND NOT EXISTS ( 
SELECT job.id,job.cid,job.cc,job.ref,job.ac,job.reference,job.status,job.jdesc
```

Comment: Hi @b3s I have changed the code to suit yours and thank you so much for shedding light on my original attempt and especially pointing out the missing SELECT. I am how ever still getting at error that was originally there regarding the PDO Execute function. I have updated my original post to show you have I have drawn up the query.

Comment: you still have some syntax errors, check my edit, if they arent errors, please provide me your table structure (both tables jobs and sheets) in order to troubleshout your query...

Comment: There is no `IF` in "SQL"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name so was I on the right track using the NOT EXISTS?

Comment: TSQL, which is sql, allows IF Statement.. if u mean "there is no _THEN_" in SQL i agree, but author's problem is not this i guess.. so lets try to help him with his issue

Comment: T-SQL is something different than "SQL" - SQL is a standard for a query language and the standard neither defines an `IF` nor a `THEN` statement. If you are answering with a specific database product in mind (Microsoft SQL Server) you should state that ("SQL" is not the same thing as "Microsoft SQL Server")

Comment: yes, i assumed he is using SQL-SERVER but you're right, we miss the information about RDBMS used here.

Comment: I do not think I am using a T-SQL because I am using a Linux server with mysql as the database

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need another query.  I think you just need to use `left join` correctly.  Put the condition on the *second* table in the `on` clause:

```
SELECT s.id, s.jid,  s.jd, s.tos, s.toffs, s.miles, s.mrate, s.r1, s.r2, s.r3, s.r4, s.r5, s.r6, s.r7, s.r8,
       j.cid, j.cc, j.ref, j.ac, j.reference, j.status, j.jdesc 
FROM jSheets s LEFT JOIN
     jobs j
     ON s.jid = j.id AND j.cc = :cc
WHERE s.jd >= :jd AND s.jd <= :jd2 
ORDER BY s.id DESC;
```

If you want to keep all *jobs*, then that should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT s.id, s.jid,  s.jd, s.tos, s.toffs, s.miles, s.mrate, s.r1, s.r2, s.r3, s.r4, s.r5, s.r6, s.r7, s.r8,
       j.cid, j.cc, j.ref, j.ac, j.reference, j.status, j.jdesc 
FROM jobs j LEFT JOIN
     jSheets s          
     ON s.jid = j.id AND s.jd >= :jd AND s.jd <= :jd2 
WHERE  j.cc = :cc 
ORDER BY s.id DESC
```

Comment: This is exactly the same apart from moving the cc condition to the on statement. This makes no difference because if no sheets are present and bound to the jobs table then it does not show the jobs with no sheets assigned.

Comment: @Robert . . . If you want to keep all *jobs* then it should be the first table in the `LEFT JOIN`.